# How to get the last conscutive <n> like records in an Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have several linked tables and I'm trying to find the sets of data where one of the sub tables has 3 (or some user-set parameter) records in a row with a given value, where the ordering is by date (in another linked table)

```
Table1
ID     LinkID   Flag
AA1    AA       30
AA2    AA       30
AA3    AA       60
AA4    AA       30
BB1    BB       30
BB2    BB       30
BB3    BB       30
BB4    BB       40

Table2
TA1    CA      2/1/2013
TA2    CA      1/1/2013
TA3    CA      12/1/2012
TA4    CA      11/1/2012
TB1    CB      2/2/2013
TB2    CB      1/1/2013
TB3    CB      12/1/2012
TB4    CB      11/2/2012
```

Other tables link them together, but I can get the AA to the CA records linked, and thus a joined result set that has

```
AA       30     2/1/2013
AA       30     1/1/2013
AA       60     12/1/2012
AA       30     11/1/2012
BB       30     1/1/2013
BB       30     2/2/2013
BB       30     12/1/2012
BB       40     11/2/2012
```

How do I query so that if they want the records with the last 3 consecutive '30' records I get only BB, but if they want the set with the last 2 consecutive '30' records I get them both?  And, of course, for any data that doesn't have a flag of 30 in the most recent record, I don't ever get that data?

I'm starting from an existing query that joins the dozen tables or so, and returns data based on the most current one being 30, and shows the one previous.  I think for this modification, I'll need to completely re-organize it, but I'm drawing a blank on how to even approach it, and the above I think shows what I'm trying to do.

I don't need working sql (I didn't provide enough data examples anyway), but rather an sql pseudo-code showing how to approach finding  consecutive records with a given value, based on ordering found in another indirectly linked table.  Or, for that matter, how to get it if it was all in one table, like the result set above.

Comment: I do not think your records are consecutive. You need to order them somehow to be truly consecutive. Then you can try using windowing functions like ...order by your_cons_date range between 1 preceding and 1 following...

Comment: Within each set they are ordered by date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you'll want to use the `LAG` and/or `LEAD` analytic functions.  So, for example,

```
LAG( flag ) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_column DESC) prior_flag_value
```

will return the prior value of the `flag` column for that `id` value based on the `date_column`.  You can look back more than one row as well

```
LAG( flag, 2 ) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_column DESC) prior_flag_value
```

will get you the value from two rows prior.  Similarly, you can use `LEAD` to get the value for the next row.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the number of records that appear consecutively together, based on the date.

To do this, do the following:

(1) enumerate the months using row_number() for each col1 value:  `row_number() over (partition by col1)` as seqnum_1.

(2) enumerate the months using row_number() for each col1, col2 combination:  `row_number() over (partition by col1, col2)` as seqnum_2.

(3) Now `seqnum_1 - seqnum_2` identifies groups of consecutive values.

(4) Count this for each group on each record:  `count(*) over (partition by col1, seqnum_1 - seqnum_2) as thegroupsize`.

Now, you can select where thegroupsize has 2 or more elements.